# ASP.Net Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

I would like to fire the ListView1_ItemUpdating event on ListView1_ItemDeleting.

Reason is whenever user press delete in listview, the record should not be physically delete from the database. There is a bit in table I need to just make it true so need to update that record.

So How could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code in `ListView1_ItemUpdating` Event

Answer (score 2):

Write a **common function to Update database** and call it in both `ListView1_ItemUpdating` and  `ListView1_ItemDeleting` events .

Pass entity to be updated to that function , when it is called from `ListView1_ItemDeleting` the bit should set true.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach maybe useful.

```
void ContactsListView_ItemUpdating(Object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  Update();      
}  
protected void CategoriesListView_OnItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
  Update();
}
```

Comment: Hi, But I would like to do it with the entity framework only. cant use those sql connection way.

Comment: @JayeshTanna where is sql connection in the above code? ` Update(); ` method you can do it with  entity framework

Comment: hi please can you give me a example of it. I am using entity framework